# make a program to run other program on C

Tags: c

I have a program that works like this

```
program1.exe program2.exe
```

I need to make it run like this

```
%USERPROFILE%\program1.exe program2.exe
```

How can that be done on C?

Comment: What does `%USERPROFILE%` mean?

Comment: is pointing to C:\Users\{username}\  where the programs are

Comment: Why do you think you need to change anything in the program if you run it like that?

Comment: This is more an exercise to me than other thing. I was looking to understant how this could be done

Comment: You just use the `system()` function to run another program. It doesn't matter how you ran the first program.

Comment: If your program already works, it should still work when you run it that way.

Answer (score 3):

From what I could see, you're using Microsoft Windows.

There are (at least) two answers to your question, a simple one, and one tied to the Windows operating system interface, usually called Win32 API.

Let's use the simple one. If your prefer to have more control about the execution of the 2nd program, please comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* system() */

int main(int argc, char* const* argv) 
{
        int rv;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("Please inform the name of the program to execute.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        rv = system(argv[1]);

        printf("Program execution returned %d\n", rv);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like to learn how I could include a way to define the path of the programs without to be prompted to insert it manually

Comment: Yup: +1.  The OP is looking for [system()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).  It's also worth mentioning [getenv()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), to read environment variables like %USERPROFILE% and %PATH%, or [getcwd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), to get the current working directory.

Comment: Hello, @dmyx. 

I shall try this little program under Windows, for I've created under Linux. It shouldn't ask for `PATH`, though, for `system()` sends it to the shell, that's aware of `PATH`. In your case it's usually either `cmd.exe` or PowerShell.